# What's the pid represent for when using eval

Tags: bash, eval

In bash shell, I wrote a function a, and in function b I used eval to call function a dynamically. But I found when using `echo $(sh -c 'echo $PPID')` in function a, it returned a pid, but I can't find this process by using `ps -p pidno`. So was it a pid number? Or what else the number represent for ?
Thanks for answering.

Comment: Strange, it works correctly in my computer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually the question you wanted to ask, but if it is, then yes, it was a pid and not something else.

Comment: If you're running this in a script then it's for the script interpreter, which may already be dead.